# Files become 0KB/empty after reverting in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I deleted a folder in the Pycharm project by mistake, then restored it in local history and found that except for the.py file that was successfully restored, other such as .pth files,.txt files, and log files of tensorboard were empty.

I wish I could restore them.